# Looking for papers within particular deep learning domain

Tags: deep-learning, supervised-learning

I have labels for training data e.g. regression / classification on top of it I have some supplementary information only for the training data that shows more detailed information on the labels (how the labels were defined). I don't have this additional information for the test / dev and real life inference scenario. I wouldn't call this additional info a weak label either but I want to use that additional information to boost the model performance.

I am looking for papers (in particular transformers) that show how to solve such problems... I don't know though how to find them as such problem as far as I know does not have its own name...to be used as a key-word. If I get few of them then I can easily go through references to build knowledge around this domain.

Titles are not descriptive enough though to figure such use case.

Any thoughts how to find them?

Comment: You could try to look at the additional information and manually engineer interesting features for your model.

Comment: @Valentas they cannot be considered as input features as they are only available in the training data subset. That's the whole problem with it.